# ImageView resize issue within Stack View

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistackview

I have been trying to create a chat bubble with caption using Swift in iOS. My strategy includes a stack view which then comprises of two arranged subviews. i.e. imageView at the top and then textView at the bottom.

When the view loads up initially, all the calculations perfectly work out and the chat bubble turns out to be perfect. But, as soon as the orientation of the view changes, the size of the imageView goes bonkers and shows incorrect height.

Does anybody have the idea how to resolve this issue?

I am using a collection view for the chat screen.

Here is the code chunk that I am using:

//after definitions of stackview, imageview and textview

//calls method to configure imageview

```
IV = UIImageView()
let imageViewWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: IV!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: size.width)
let imageViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: IV!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: size.height)
IV.addConstraints([imageViewWidthConstraint, imageViewHeightConstraint])
let fixedWidth = size.width
let fixedHeight = size.height
let newSize = IV.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: fixedHeight))
asyncImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0, width: max(Int(newSize.width),Int(fixedWidth)), height: max(Int(newSize.height),Int(fixedHeight)))
IV.contentMode = .scaleToFill
       
IV.clipsToBounds = true
IV.layer.cornerRadius = 15
IV.layoutIfNeeded()
IV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
```

//then calls method to configure text view

```
TV = UITextView()
TV.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
TV.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
TV.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
TV.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
TV.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
TV.text = caption.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
TV.isSelectable = true
TV.isEditable = false
TV.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
TV.sizeToFit()
TV.isScrollEnabled = false
let captionLineHeight = (asyncTextView.font?.lineHeight ?? 0)
let numberOfLines = asyncTextView.numberOfLines(textView: TV)

let captionHeight = 20+captionLineHeight*CGFloat(numberOfLines)
TV.backgroundColor = .cyan
TV.layoutIfNeeded()
        
let textViewWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: TV!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: size.width)
let textViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: TV!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: captionHeight)
TV.addConstraints([textViewWidthConstraint, textViewHeightConstraint])
TV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
```

//then calls method to configure stack view

```
SV = UIStackView()
SV.axis = .vertical
SV.alignment = .fill
SV.distribution = .fill
       
SV.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0, width: size.width, height: IV.frame.height + TV.frame.height)

SV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: IV.frame.height+TV.frame.height).isActive = true
SV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive =  true
SV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
```

Note:
size.width = 315
size.height = 225

Also, using library JSQMessage for rendering the chat bubble, without adding the caption the cell works just fine, but now when i am dealing with caption, these were the changes that i made to my code that i have shared above, which does not seem to work when the device orientation is changed.

[Before changing orientation of the view:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRiuI.jpg)

[After changing orientation of the view, imageview getting stretched:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaaga.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you're doing a number of things that you don't need to do and/or shouldn't do. Your code shows calculations using `size.width` and `size.height` but you haven't shown us where `size` is coming from. It would help if you show us an image of what you want your cell to look like.

Comment: well the 'size' here is the mediaview size. for example, size.height = 225 and size.width = 315. the imageview views takes up this size while rest of the calculations are for the textView and the stackview.

Comment: Please review [ask]. You need to show us your ***actual code*** (what you've shown is missing a lot of information). You need to show us an image of how it looks when it is correct, and how it looks when it's not.

Comment: Hi @DonMag , thank you for guiding me, I just updated the post, hopefully that helps.

Comment: OK - couple comments (and I don't mean this to sound harsh)... I don't know why you're trying to use `JSQMessage` which hasn't been updated in over 5 years. I ***strongly suggest*** you go through some auto-layout tutorials, because the code you've posted is a very wrong approach. I'd also suggest you do some searching -- for example, searching for `swift chat bubble` returns many articles, tutorials, examples, etc... written much more recently.